# Passing arguments to a function referenced by a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

#### The Issue

I am writing a file parser for program input files that can be somewhat deconstructed to dictionaries: that is, in the input file, there are multi-level 'dicts' containing 'key-value pairs'.

I have a keywords dictionary which tells a `read` function which keys to read, and how to parse the key values.

For example, you can see in the code excerpt below that when `datum` is read, the value should be parsed with the function `HelperFunctions.split_to_floats`:

```
'datum': HelperFunctions.split_to_floats
```

#### The Goal

What I would like to do is be able to pass in arguments, such that I do not have to make function permutations for each possible type of i.e. value delimiter.

For example, to restructure the `keywords` dictionary in something like:

```
keywords = {
    '_root': str,
    'units': HelperFunctions._split(LINE,to=str,delim=','),
    'datum': HelperFunctions._split(LINE,to=float,delim=' ')
    }
```

#### Code Sample

A full, workable demo of what I currently have is reproduced below:

```
class HelperFunctions:

    def comma_split_to_strings(string:str) -> list:
        # Returns a list of strings
        return string.split(',')

    def split_to_floats(string:str) -> list:
        # Returns a 1D list of floats
        return list(map(float,string.split()))


keywords = {
    '_root': str,
    'units': HelperFunctions.comma_split_to_strings,
    'datum': HelperFunctions.split_to_floats
    }

card = {}
key = 'units'
value = 'Pa,kg,km'

if key in keywords:
    cast = keywords[key]

    card[key] = cast(value)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you are looking for is [partial](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in functools.  It lets you create a function with some of parameters bound to values such that you can call the returned function later with the missing values.

```py
from functools import partial

# Bind the parameters you want to "freeze"
keywords = {
    '_root': str,
    'units': partial(HelperFunctions._split, to=str, delim=','),
    'datum': partial(HelperFunctions._split, to=float, delim=' ')
    }

# The later you just need to provide LINE
keywords['units'](LINE)
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `functools.partial`?

```
from functools import partial

keywords = {
    '_root': str,
    'units': partial(HelperFunctions._split, to=str, delim=','),
    'datum': partial(HelperFunctions._split, to=float, delim=' ')
}
```